# How do you send HTML content with SendGrid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sendgrid

Trying to send HTML content in a SendGrid email header. I am getting drop email. The error is "REASON: Invalid SMTPAPI header"

This is my email template code

```
 <%body%>
--|ALERT_MESSAGE|--
```

Here is the content I want to send (ROR string)

```
      content = "<p>The system following info. [#{message}] <a href='#{url}'>#{url}</a></p>"
```

Here is my header code (self in this case is the header)

```
      self.add_category("System Email")
      self.add_filter('templates', 'enable', 1) 
      self.add_filter('templates', 'template_id', 'sdfs-f8fd6029') 
      self.add_substitution('--|MESSAGE|--', [content])
      self.set_tos(SENDGRID_EMAILS)
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if you are using a template, you need to specify some kind of body in the actual message, so that means you need to pass the `html` parameter i your request. This is an artifact due to transactional templates being added to the existing endpoint. A new mail sending endpoint is in the works that will not require text or html to be defined if a template is used.